# Supernatural book in which the main character was trapped in the cellar of a house, because his master was dating a witch who regained her memories

Tags: story-identification, books, horror, medieval

It’s a supernatural book. It took place in the medieval era. I remember reading it in middle school.

It had to do with a boy who got mentored by an old guy. These details are vague because I don’t remember much, but I do remember that, in one of the books, the main character was trapped in the cellar of a house, because his master was dating a witch who regained her memories. I don’t believe the boy had supernatural powers. I do remember that his mother was some powerful being.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover? And since you implied that this book was part of a series, do you recall roughly how books there were in the series?

Comment: Hi Ruby. What did the witch have to do with the boy being trapped in the cellar? Was it the witch who had trapped him there?

Comment: If I remember correctly it was a book later in the series and the boy and the master went to his other house the witch was stays there being forced to drink a memory forgetting potion do she doesn’t remember anything and the master is in love with her

Comment: I read the series roughly in 2019 I can’t remember anything about the title but there were 5 books that I read but there was at least 1-2 more i remember I think in the 2 or 3 book that the boy and master had to go do something to do with catacombs